# How does "arguments" keyword work in Javascript?

Tags: arrays, arguments

I came across this little exercise and I am not really sure how the "arguments" keyword works here and also why (...arr) is placed where it is as it is outside of the a's declaration parentheses...

```
var arr = ["tic", "tac", "toe"];
var a = (
    function() {
    return arguments[2];
    }
)(...arr);
console.log(a);
```

Could you please explain or point me to a relevant source as I am not sure what I am actually looking for? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is the array of arguments passed to the current function. In the above code example, the function within the parentheses is being called with `...args` as the arguments.

In JS, you need not name a function to call it. The above code is equivalent to the following:

```
var arr = ["tic", "tac", "toe"];
var callme = function() {
    return arguments[2];
}
var a = callme(...arr);
console.log(a);
```

The arguments in the function call are being passed with "spread syntax."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

So the function is being called with the values of `arr` as it's arguments, and is returning the third argument `arguments[2]`.